# Inverting the A/C VSV Switch

Tags: ac, carburetor

I bought a 2E Carburetor for my 4G13 Engine. My Problem is that 2E Carburetor Idle Up A/C Vacuum Actuator needs vacuum when the engine is on and when the A/C is On, the idle up vsv will be Off (or no vacuum at all). My Stock Variable Venturi Carburetor's Idle Up Vacuum actuator is on the opposite operation. A/C off, no Vacuum. A/C on, Vacuum is present (kicking the idle). Is there a way to Invert the Switch like A/C off, Vacuum On and A/C on, Vacuum Off(kicking the idle)?

PS. Don't advise me to stick will stock carburetor because i don't like it. I bought a 2E because my Stock Water Choke is not working at all. Just Respect my decision.

Comment: Can you switch to direct vacuum (off the manifold) to solve this?

Comment: @Paulster2 I already did a direct vacuum off the manifold. Runs fine but the Idle Up Vacuum is not kicking when the A/C is on. To do that is when the A/C switch is on, the Idle Up Vacuum Switch will turn off and the solenoid kicks in.